# remove volume on missing dynamic disk

Tags: windows-server-2003, mirror, diskpart, dynamic-disk

I had 2 drives in my Server 2003 PDC

1 of the drives went bad and was replaced. Now i show the working drive, the new drive and a missing disk. I am trying to delete the missing disk but am not able to because it contains a volume that was part of the original mirror.

basically. I need to rebuild the mirror between the remaining working disk and the new replacement disk.

The "break mirror" function is not available, however "remove mirror" is available.

My question is, if i use "remove mirror" on the missing disk, will it delete the volume (and my data) on my remaining good drive also ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove mirror won't damage the data on your existing volume. You're fine to go ahead and "Remove Mirror" and then "Add Mirror" using the new disk. Don't just take my word for it, though-- here's what Microsoft says: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758037(WS.10).aspx

There are no PDC's in Windows 2003, BTW. Perhaps I'm just being a terminology freak, but it's just a "DC". If you only have one you would do yourself an immense favor to spend $1,000.00 and get another Windows Server license and another box to function as a secondary replica of Active Directory. It's a really, really cheap insurance policy and makes disaster recovery a *lot* easier.

Comment: thanks for the PDC reminder. I go way back so it's a habbit sometimes, cmd is still dos prompt for me most times :)

Comment: >smile<  Hope your disk replacement went alright.